# Mexican tourist visa application for Iranian citizen

Tags: tourist-visas, mexico, iranian-citizens

I just would like to check if I can apply for a Mexican tourist visa as an Iranian citizen.

Comment: What research have you done? Why do you think you would not?

Comment: What does the website of the Mexican embassy in Iran say? Or the website of whichever branch of the Mexican government issues visas? It's always better to use official sources.

Comment: Do you have a visa or residence permit from [the US, Canada, the UK, Japan, or a Schengen country](https://embamex.sre.gob.mx/iran/index.php/es/2016-03-29-08-29-33/visas)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a visa and required to book an appointment at a Mexican consulate.

> A visa is required for travel to Mexico. The Consulate of Mexico requires applicants to apply for visas directly and a personal appearance may be necessary at the nearest Mexican Consulate. We recommend that you contact the consulate to obtain the most current requirements and make an appointment if necessary.

Another quote:

> Citizens of Iran residing in Iran must apply for a visa to Mexico in person at the nearest consulate of Mexico in Iran. Please note, application procedures and fees may vary by location. If there is no consulate of Mexico in Iran there may be a consulate of Mexico in a neighboring country that covers the jurisdiction of Iran.

([Source](https://www.visahq.com/mexico/requirements/iran/resident-iran/))

Comment: What is "The visa HQ"?

Comment: @MJeffryes edited

Comment: Where is the quote from?

Comment: @MJeffryes added another quote with reference

Comment: Mexico offers visa exemptions to people who hold visas or residence permits in any of several countries.  Does this not apply to citizens of Iran?